# Hadoop Reducer Timeouts

Tags: hadoop, timeout

My reducer is timing out for some reason. I try -Dmapred.task.timeout to change the timeouts but the timeout value doesn't seem to change. Also I am unable to configure the number of mappers and reducers through the command line. My logs seem to be clear and the tasktracker times out. I do call an external web service, but that is not the reason for timeouts. If the amount of datapoints in the input file are reduced, I donot see these timeouts often.

Comment: Do you call reporter.progress?

Comment: Yes, I do call reporter.progress()

Comment: Is  task timeout not configurable through the Hadoop API?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust `mapred.task.timeout` (value is is milliseconds) in `mapred-site.xml`.

Ensure its updated on all nodes (jobtracker+tasktrackers) and restart the `jobtracker` and all `tasktrackers`.